# Scanner does not assign value to the arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

```
import java.util.*;

public class TestScoreTestor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ArrayList<Integer> score = new ArrayList<Integer>();
//        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner test = new Scanner(System.in);      
        System.out.println("Enter the scores(enter the input by Ctrl+z): ");

//   int a = keyboard.nextInt();  // **** add this to swallow EOL token

        while(test.hasNextInt()) {
             score.add(test.nextInt());
        }   

        test.close();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(score.size());
// the scores are not involved  
        for (int i = 1; i <= score.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(score.get(i));
        }

        Scores grade = new Scores(score);
        System.out.println("Your grade: " + grade.getLetterGrade());

    }

}
```

The above is my code and I have a problem of assigning value from Scanner test to ArrayList score. When I run the code, this shows that

```
Enter the scores(enter the input by Ctrl+z): 
90 90 90
0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at Lab05Q6.Scores.averageScore(Scores.java:29)
    at Lab05Q6.Scores.getLetterGrade(Scores.java:36)
    at Lab05Q6.TestScoreTestor.main(TestScoreTestor.java:29)
```

"0" is the size of the arrayList, so I think that there may be some problem during the value adding

```
while(test.hasNextInt()) {
             score.add(test.nextInt());
        }
```

and also I have tried the solutions for others' questions similar to mine,but it does not work. Could you please help me with these question?

Comment: Exception is thrown from Scores class, so provide its code please.

Comment: Yes Please provide the code for Score class

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions and that might help you get it off better :

```
   while(test.hasNextInt()) {
             score.add(test.nextInt());
        }
```

This loop will terminate only if you enter some non-digit character. Space and new line will not terminate the loop.

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= score.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(score.get(i));
        }
```

Exception you posted, will never be reached because you will always end up into index out of bound exception. Also, you are starting with index = 1, you might want to start from index 0. Not sure about your logic in Score class.

Also, as what others said, if you posted exception from any class, please provide that.

Comment: @Russiancold if you downvoted, let me clarify. Isnt it clear to you by looking at the program what is wrong here. But you are so adamant that you still want to see the Scores class and instead helping someone and showing him light. This platform is to help someone, encourage someone.

Comment: your answer doesn't solve the problem, that's why I downvoted it. Am not I right? I always would like to help anybody. But I'm  passing the same strict demands on SO. So I'm trying to to the same. Sorry.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, i appreciate that. Keep doing good work and help others. But at the same time do not get overwhelm with strict demands or restrictions. If you believe this should be downvoted, it is okay.